# what is the best way to use CPLEX solver in MacOS?

Tags: c++, xcode, cplex

Recently I switched from Windows to macOS. in windows, I always coded my, model, in C++ in Visual Studio. in Mac I tried Xcode and visual studio and failed. I have found some tutorials for Xcode but some steps have changed in the recent version of Xcode. I would appreciate any suggestion of IDEs that work with CPLEX concert technology.

Comment: What problem did you encounter? Seeking recommendations for software is off topic here

Comment: I think I found out the problem. it seems like CPLEX is not supported on m1 chips yet.

Comment: That's correct: as of this writing, CPLEX is not officially supported on the M1 chips.  But it should not be hard to get it to work, provided you add the flag `-arch x86_64` in your makefiles.

Comment: can you please provide a link or tutorial on how to do that? I added a "-DIL_STD" in the custom compiler flag. is this the same section where I have to add the "-arch x86_64" flag?